# Data binding not working?

Tags: angularjs

The browser only renders `{"data":[]}` to the page and does not update once the promise is resolved, however `window.sc` shows that the data is fetched and added to the scope successfully, but the browser does not show this. Why is this happening?

index.html.jade

```
head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title Badsey Fantasy Cricket
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js')
    script(src='https://www.parse.com/downloads/javascript/parse-1.2.18.min.js')
    script(src='vendor/facebook/all.js')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='index.css')

body()
    div(ng-app='fantasyCricket')
        div(ng-controller='PlayersCtrl')
            h1 {{players}}
    script(src='index.js')
```

index.js.coffee

```
fantasyCricket = angular.module('fantasyCricket', [() ->
    # Initialises Parse SDK.
    Parse.initialize("####", "####")

    # Initialises Parse FacebookUtils.
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
        appId: "####"
        cookie: true
        xfbml: true
    })
])

fantasyCricket.factory('Players', () ->
    obj = {
        data: []
        refresh: () ->
            (new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend('player'))).find()
    }
    obj
)

fantasyCricket.controller('PlayersCtrl', ['$scope', 'Players', ($scope, Players) ->
    $scope.players = Players
    window.sc = $scope

    Players.refresh().done((players) ->
        $scope.players.data.splice.apply($scope.players.data, [0, 0].concat(players))
    ).fail((err) -> alert('Failed to load players'))
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to call $scope.$apply in the refresh callback

```
Players.refresh().done((players) ->
        $scope.players.data.splice.apply($scope.players.data, [0, 0].concat(players))
        $scope.$apply();
    ).fail((err) -> alert('Failed to load players'))
```

you can also use push instead of splice

```
 $scope.players.data.push.apply($scope.players.data,players);
 $scope.$apply();
```